# Keep footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a layout where the footer is inside the body, because i have a sidebar 100% height.

The fact is that I need to keep the footer at the bottom when the height of the body content is less than the screen height.

Here I attach a [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ndmez9y1/) where can be seen that the footer is just below the last line of the body.

Also, when the body content height is higher than screen height, the footer should follow the last line.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="header">GENERAL HEADER</div> <div id="main_body">
    <div id="sidebar">SIDE</div>
    <div id="body">
        the content
        <div class="footer">general footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*           {margin:0; padding:0;}
html        {overflow: hidden;font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:100;}
body        {background:#fff; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;overflow: auto;}
#main_body  {
    background:#fff;
    height:100%;
    padding:50px 0 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    min-width:900px;
}
#header     {
  background:#119911;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  min-width:960px;
  height:50px;
  display:flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
}
#sidebar    {background:#f2f2f2; float:left; width:60px; height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
#body       {
    background:#c2c2c2;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#551111;
    color:#fff;
    border-top:1px solid #CDCDCD;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/?

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/jcypsg52/ ] try footer position absolute with bottom 0

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Yes, almost but the question is that I do not want to overlap the sidebar. I want to keep the footer inside the #body

Comment: @Apalabrados set position relative on ID body or you can set on class .footer left:60px; [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/jcypsg52/1/ ]

Answer (score 2):

I have added the following properties in the class **footer**.

```
  bottom:0px;
  position:fixed;
```

Try this:

```css
*           {margin:0; padding:0;}
html        {overflow: hidden;font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:100;}
body        {background:#fff; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;overflow: auto;}
#main_body  {
    background:#fff;
    height:100%;
    padding:50px 0 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    min-width:900px;
}
#header     {
  background:#119911;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  min-width:960px;
  height:50px;
  display:flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
}
#sidebar    {background:#f2f2f2; float:left; width:60px; height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
#body       {
    background:#c2c2c2;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#551111;
    color:#fff;
    border-top:1px solid #CDCDCD;
    bottom:0px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">GENERAL HEADER</div>
<div id="main_body">
    <div id="sidebar">SIDE</div>
    <div id="body">
        the content
        <div class="footer">general footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad!!, @Apalabrados If it worked for you..please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, 2 minutes remaining to be able to accept it. One question.... when the #body content is higher than screen height, i wish the footer goes just below the last line of the content and should no appear... how can be accomplished?

Comment: If I understood your point..the footer is going beyond the scroll because..of the scroll bar which you have added to the body tag. You can keep the footer above the scroll bar by keeping the bottom property with bottom:12px something, or else trying removing the overflow property or reducing the content height as required.

Comment: Would you mind modifying your code snippet to see what you are trying to explain me? Thanks.

Comment: @Apalabrados I have forked a new fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyaditya/hgbuhhcr/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#551111;
    color:#fff;
    border-top:1px solid #CDCDCD;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This will put your footer at the bottom.This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with position: absolute;.

Comment: Yes, almost but the question is that I do not want to overlap the sidebar. I want to keep the footer inside the #body

Comment: @Apalabrados Check my edited answer. I have remove right and left:0 from css